# C programming codeblocks not showing errors when i try to build and run

Tags: c, codeblocks

cant find compiler executable in your confugured search path's for GNU GCC compiler

Comment: Where is MinGW installed? If you haven't already installed it separately, why not just download the version of the Code::Blocks installer that provides MinGW with it? Code::Blocks is pretty good at finding a compiler if you have one installed in a reasonably normal location. I suspect you don't have MinGW installed.

Comment: where should I place it when i download it?

Comment: @Munywokikiteme I suspect anywhere , maybe a downloads folder or such ?